# How can I reuse a text string within and across Confluence pages?

Tags: confluence

I'd like to minimize the number of times I have to type dates and version numbers across release notes pages and such on Confluence.

How can I reuse a text string within the same page as well as across pages on Confluence?

Right now, I have a bit of text (for example, a version number) which is typed out in multiple locations:

- Page A

  - Top of page
  - Middle of page
  - End of page
- Page B

I'd like to be able to type the value once and have it automatically appear in all places.

There are multiple bits of text I'd like to do this with on one page.

The closest I've found so far is the [MultiExcerpt macro](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/169/multi-excerpt?hosting=cloud&tab=overview), but unfortunately it displays all content with newline wrapping instead of inline and that's a dealbreaker for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [Comala Metadata](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/5295/comala-metadata?hosting=server&tab=overview), sounds like what you are looking for. 
Disclaimer, I work in the company behind that app, in Comalatech.

Regards,
Gorka

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Confluence own [Include Macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/include-page-macro-139514.html) or the Excerpt Macro. The include macro can be inline if you keep it on the same line in the editor.

Comment: Include will include an entire page, which I am not looking for.
Excerpt does what I want, but only allows one instance per page. That's why I'm using MultiExcerpt. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

There is an official extension called Multi Excerpt. It works like Excerpt, but you can use more then one for one page.

Comment: Thanks, but I already linked to this in my question and explained that it doesn't allow in-line display which is a deal-breaker.